# Duplicates end up in list despite "if statement"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay, I was working on a code that would give every possible combination of the scrambled letters you input.  Here it is:

```
import random, math

words = []
original = raw_input("What do you need scrambled? ")

def word_scramble(scrambled):

    original_length = len(scrambled)
    loops = math.factorial(original_length)

    while loops > 0:
        new_word = []

        used_numbers = []

        while len(new_word) < original_length:

            number = random.randint(0, original_length - 1)

            while number in used_numbers:
                number = random.randint(0, original_length - 1)

            while number not in used_numbers:
                used_numbers.append(number)
                new_word.append(scrambled[number])

        if new_word not in words:
            words.append(("".join(str(x) for x in new_word)))
            loops -= 1

word_scramble(original)

print ("\n".join(str(x) for x in words))
```

The problem is, it still gives duplicates, even though it isn't supposed to.  For instance, I can input "imlk" and will sometimes get "milk" twice, while still only giving me 24 permutations, meaning some permutations are being excluded.  The:

```
if new_word not in words:
    words.append(("".join(str(x) for x in new_word)))
    loops -= 1
```

is supposed to prevent duplicates from being in the list.  So I'm not really sure what the issue is.  And sorry that the main title of the question was so vague/weird.  I wasn't really sure how to phrase it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):**

> itertools.permutations(iterable[, r])
>
> Return successive r length permutations of elements in the iterable.
>
> If r is not specified or is None, then r defaults to the length of the
>   iterable and all possible full-length permutations are generated.

```
import itertools
word=raw_input()
scramble_all = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.permutations(word)]
print scramble_all
```

**Output:**

> ['milk', 'mikl', 'mlik', 'mlki', 'mkil', 'mkli', 'imlk', 'imkl',
>   'ilmk', 'ilkm', 'ikml', 'iklm', 'lmik', 'lmki', 'limk', 'likm',
>   'lkmi', 'lkim', 'kmil', 'kmli', 'kiml', 'kilm', 'klmi', 'klim']

Answer (score 6):

How about `itertools.permutations`?

```
import itertools
original = raw_input("What do you need scrambled? ")
result = [''.join(s) for s in itertools.permutations(original)]
```

Comment: The length by default is the length of the iterable. So `len(original)` is not required.

Comment: @SilentMonk: Good catch. Thanks.

Comment: Standard library FTW.

Comment: Oops.  I should have mentioned I was trying to write my own function.  I'm still learning, and that was just a little project I thought I might try.  But that would work as well, so thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
if new_word not in words:
    words.append(("".join(str(x) for x in new_word)))
    loops -= 1
```

`new_word` is a list of letters, but `words` contains strings not lists of letters. They're in different formats, so the check will always succeed.

For instance, you might get the check:

```
if ['m', 'i', 'l', 'k'] not in ['imlk', 'milk', 'klim']
```

rather than

```
if 'milk' not in ['imlk', 'milk', 'klim']
```

By the way, your algorithm is going to scale very badly the more letters it needs to scramble. It relies upon randomly stumbling upon unused words, which is fast at first, but slow the more words are used.

You'll be better off if you can figure out a way to enumerate the permutations in a predictable order without guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding your original question, I can provide a better solution for generating all combinations. Just as a reminder, there is a difference between all possible *combinations* and *permutations*.

A combination is where the ordering of a subset of elements from some set does not matter. For example, "bac" and "abc" are equal combinations. The opposite is true for a permutation where order does matter, "abc" and "bac" are not equal permutations. Combinations are all possible subsets of a set, while permutations are all possible orderings of a set.

With that in mind, here is an algorithm to generate all possible combinations (subsets) of a set.

```
def all_subsets( L ):
    if L == []:
        return []
    result = []
    for i in range( len ( L ) ):
        result += [ [ L[ i ] ] ]
        result += [ e + [ L[ i ] ] for e in all_subsets( L[ i+1 : ] ) ]
    return result
```